# Grabbing the page URL and submitting it when form is submitted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a form that will appear when a button on an item page is pressed to receive a quote. Since there are many items, I want to know the URL of the page the form was received on and I am not sure how to achieve this.

My question is how do I grab the URL of the page the button was pressed on and then submit it along with the form as a hidden value so that I am aware what item was requested for a quote? Here is my code for the form. The Source URL input is just a placeholder.

```
<form action="http://et-signup.topright.com/oemSignup/subscribe" name="subscribeForm" method="post" onsubmit="alert('Thank You We Will Contact You Shortly'); return true;">
<input type="hidden" name="urlOfSubscribeThankYouPage" value="http://myurl.com">
<input type="hidden" name="urlOfErrorPage" value="http://myurl.com">
<input type="hidden" name="urlOfUnsubscribeThankYouPage" value="http://myurl.com">
<input type="hidden" name="mid" value="6286675">
<input type="hidden" name="listName" value="Item Page List - 52083">
Email Address: <input type="email" required="required" name="emailAddress"/> <br/>
        First Name: <input name="profile.First Name"><br/>
        Last Name: <input name="profile.Last Name"><br/>
        Company Name: <input name="profile.Company Name"><br/>
        Phone: <input name="profile.Phone"><br/>
        Estimated Quantity: <input name="profile.Estimated Quantity"><br/>
        Comments: <input name="profile.Comments"><br/>
        Small: <input name="profile.Small"><br/>
        Medium: <input name="profile.Medium"><br/>
        Large: <input name="profile.Large"><br/>
        Extra Large: <input name="profile.Extra Large"><br/>
        2XL: <input name="profile.2XL"><br/>
        3XL: <input name="profile.3XL"><br/>
        Source URL: <input name="profile.Source URL"><br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="SubAction" value="sub_add_update">
    <input type="submit" value="Join">
</form>
```

Comment: You mean the HTTP Referrer? You can always check that server side :)

Comment: @Brunis this all depends on what he is using for his server code. On different langauges it is different to use. Sometimes better to just get as a url param.

Comment: It is definitely easier in this case for me to use a url param than to do it server side.

Comment: @NoahHuppert, a post always has to come from somewhere and inspecting the HTTP Referrer variable regardles of language is the way to get it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be looking for the referrer variable.

If you are using plain html and javascript you can find it using:

```
document.referrer;
```

In PHP:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

in ASP.NET:

```
Request.UrlReferrer
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This seems to be the right way for me to do it. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

What I do for these kind of 'meta' options is make a hidden `input` field like so.

```
<input id="pageUrlInput" type="text" name="pageUrl" style="display: none;">
```

Then populate the value of this on document ready

```
$(document).function(){
    $('#pageUrlInput').val(window.location.href);
});
```

This will populate the value of the hidden input field with the page url(`window.location.href`). Then just get the `pageUrl` param when processing the form on a server

Comment: Please, explain downvotes ! Im not saying this one should not get one, but its very annoying to see downvotes and no reasons...

Comment: @avcajaraville I believe it was someone(not naming names) in the OP comments who suggested using HTTP Refererer who didn't provide an example but saw these as not that method, so wrong.

Comment: @Brunis but like most people on this site, I'm not going to. Because it is one of many correct ways to complete what was asked.